# Python Error: (2, 'No such file or directory') while email file in python

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send a file through `EmailMessage` but I'm getting the error `No such file or directory`. The file is available in the mentioned directory, so
why am I not able to email the file?

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage

def email_file(recipient, title, email_msg, file_name):
    try:
        msg = EmailMessage(title, email_msg, to=recipient)
        msg.attach_file(file_name)
        msg.send()
    except Exception as exception:
        print exception.args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    excel_file = '/home/geeks/test.pdf'
    recipient = 'email'
    email_msg = 'Please find placement report of this week'
    title = 'Status Report'
    email_file(recipient, title, email_msg, excel_file)
```

**Permission of file is**

```
 -rw-r----- 1 geeks geeks      83079 Jan 19 02:17  test.pdf
```

Comment: make sure the user which executes the program has read permission on the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
No such file or directory
```

Itself indicate the answer.

Either your file does not exist at the path you have given or it does not have enough permission to read file.

Comment: permission of file is `-rw-r----- 1 geeks geeks      83079 Jan 19 02:17  test.pdf`

Comment: My fault, I while creating file, I was searching the file will some space before the file name, So I was not able to find the file.. `'/home/geeks/ test.pdf'`